# How to start animation of pseudo elements start little bit late than parent element in css?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm creating a preloader in CSS. It is basically 3 dots growing it's size rhythmically. The preloader looks like the image below.

[image: How my preloader looks]

To create this preloader, I created a box having `border-radius:50%;` so that it becomes round. Then used pseudo elements, `::after` and `::before` to create another identical looking two circles. The middle circle is the original one. Other two circles are psedo elements, so they become child elements of the original. There's a animation which scales up the three balls. Pseudo element inherit the animation from parent. I want to let pseudo elements start the animation little bit late than the parent.

```
.preloader{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
    animation: resize 2s linear infinite;
}

.preloader::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    border-radius: inherit;
    left: -15px;
}

.preloader::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    border-radius: inherit;
    left: 15px;
}
```

Note that I have used an animation called resize in the preloader class.

```
animation: resize 2s linear infinite;
```

The resize animation use transform property to scale up and down the preloader.

```
@keyframes resize{
    50%{
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
}
```

Now when this class is tested on the browser, all three balls scale in the same rate. But I need to make the second and third balls small relative to the first ball when the animation starts and when the animation goes on, all the balls should scale rhythmically as shown below.

[image: preloader in action]

[image]

[image]

I know everything scales up in the same rate without creating desired effect is because all three balls start the animation in the same time. So I added `animation-delay: 1s;` to the pseudo element before and `animation-delay: 3s;` to after. But it did nothing. I guess it is because pseudo elements inherits all parent elements properties, so the pseudo elements `animation-delay` works in a different layer.

Is there any method to let pseudo elements start the animation little bit late than the parent element. This is possible when I use three separate classes without using pseudo element but I want to know whether this is possible with pseudo elements because I have to add only one `<div>` element when I use pseudo classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that `.preloader` contains itself, `.preloader::before` and `.preloader::after`, and you can't animate `.preloader` without animating `.preloader::before` and `.preloader::after`. You should create an additional span inside and add animations to `.preloader span`, `.preloader::before`, and `.preloader::after` - that is the most popular solution to this issue.